# Can I use a separate Azure account for Standard storage

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up a separate Azure account to use as a storage space.
I want this separate so that any usage of the storage will not interfere with our websites bandwidth.
Every time I try to set one up I get my current account portal pages.

Has anyone tried to do this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but... Azure storage accounts are separate from websites. You you please edit to explain your question further?

Answer (score 1):

Storage and your web apps are two different azure services, so one will not "eat into the bandwidth" of the other.

However, if what you meant to ask was: I have a BizSpark/MSDN account, and i dont want this storage "eating into" my free monthly credits... You pay what you use, so you wouldnt be "saving" money that way.

If you want two wholely different Azure accounts, you will need two different microsoft accounts. Log out of your microsoft account (and/or open a private browser tab) and then create a new one.

Hopefully that answers your question, although unless there is a reason to gave two completely different logins/accounts it is a lot of extra work for not much reward.

For me, i have an account for me personally, and one for my company, and that is a hassle enough already.